# How to change <p> in css with a custom theme?

Tags: css

In a WP site developed with a custom theme, I saw that font size of the paragraph tag seems to be defined in

```
/wp-content/themes/nameofcustomtheme/style.css?ver=1.1.11
```

I have tried to change font-size to 18px in `style.css` located there, but now the inspector says that

is defined by a css file located at

```
/?sccss=1&ver=4.6
```

And that the font size remains 16px.

How could I change the paragraph tag font size?

Comment: First off, are you working from a child theme or are you editting the theme files directly? It is advised against editting directly 

Secondly, it could be that the theme compiles its scss files to the final style.css in which case you should edit the font-size in those. But given the spase information it is hard to tell what is going on

Comment: Working on style.css, this is in the child theme. How could I work on the ' scss files to the final style.css'? I didn't find a such file on the server

Comment: They are probably created in the parent theme. But the issue is probably that your child theme style is loaded before the parent styles hence overwritten. You could probably get away with using !important on your p style. But I am going to give a suggestion/answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on a child theme you could try the following. This requires that you have removed @import from your child themes style.css or removed the hook, that loads the parent stylesheet in your child themes functions.php.

Add this to your functions.php in the child theme:

```
function wp_enq_theme_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enq_theme_styles' );
```

What this code does is enqueuing the parent style first and then the child style. The array part of the child-style tells wordpress that the child style is dependent on the parent style thus it is loaded after the parent style. Hence your child styles will override the parent styles.

Hope this helps.

PS. you can always read more about it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: How can I "remove @import from your child themes style.css or remove the hook, that loads the parent stylesheet in your child themes functions.php"?

Comment: In any case '!important' in p style in 'style.css' is working now